# CSS "crop" images, but align in center vertically

Tags: html, css, image

I'm currently cropping images with CSS as so:

```
<div class="crop">
    <img src="image.png" alt="">
</div>

.crop {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.crop img {
width: 150px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

This way, it aligns the image within the container horizontally. However, I have no idea how to align the image vertically in the center (so it's right in the middle). Any help?

Comment: I think it will be much easier by using css "clip" http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically align an image inside div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div)

Comment: max-height=150px;  try it, your image will be fixed

Answer (score 8):

/* Just gonna leave this here.. */

```
.crop {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 8px;
}
.crop img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use these classes :

```css
.center-crop-img {
  object-fit: none; /* Do not scale the image */
  object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
  width: 100%;
}

.center-crop-img-cover {
  object-fit: cover; /* cover image */
  object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
  width: 100%;
}

.center-crop-img-contain {
  object-fit: contain; /* contain the image */
  object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
  width: 100%;
}

.center-crop-img-scale-down {
  object-fit: scale-down; /* scale-down the image */
  object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @RanSch, you can crop the image using **clip** attribute.

```
.imgClass{
   clip:rect(top,right,bottom,0px);
   margin-top: //someValue or
   vertical-align: middle; //or
   top: //someValue or
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
 .crop img{top:50%; left:50%;}
```

OR USE-

```
 .crop img{vertical-align:middle;}
```

Comment: syntax mistake you need an opening curly brace `{` instead of an opening bracket `(`

Comment: BTW, the above will cause the images top to go down 50% you need to add half the images height using a negative margin for the above code to be effective.